# Create a simple page that returns a JSON response

Tags: java, jsp

The team that works on the client side in my project has asked me to write a sample test page, and give them a working URL that they can hit and get back 200. They have asked me to also give a sample request body.
Here is the request body I will be giving to them.

```
{
"MyApp": {
    "mAppHeader": {
        "appId": "",
        "personId": "",
        "serviceName": "",
        "clientIP": "",
        "requestTimeStamp": "",     
        "encoding": "",
        "inputDataFormat": "",
        "outputDataFormat": "",
        "environment": ""
    },
   "requestPayload": {
        "header": {
            "element": ""
        },
        "body": {
            "request": {
                "MyTestApp": {
                    "data": {
                        "AuthenticationRequestData": {
                            "appId": "",
                            "appPwd": ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

To develop the sample page, I have no idea where to start. Please go easy on your downvotes (in case the question seems irrelevant) as I have no experience working on JSP Servlets.

Here is what I have as of now. Its a simple login page -

```
    <%@ page language="java" 
    contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
    pageEncoding="windows-1256"
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="TestClient">

            AppId       
            <input type="text" name="appID"/><br>       

            AppPassword
            <input type="text" name="appPwd"/>

            <input type="submit" value="submit">            

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my servlet class -

```
 package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestClient extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TestClient() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/json");
        App app = new App();
        app.setAppID(request.getParameter("appID"));
        app.setAppPassword(request.getParameter("appPwd"));     
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

My App is a simple Java class that has appID, and appPassword with getters and setters, so I am not going to post that here.

My question is - Am I doing this right or 100% wrong? Please give me your advice.

Comment: If you can point me to links where I can get a better idea on what needs to be done that's fine too. Or if you can give me some example, that's OK too. I am just clarifying my approach here. I don't feel very confident I have done it right, so need some advice.

Comment: If they're asking for a 200 response with JSON data they're probably planning to use an AJAX request. That means there's probably an expectation that the user will already be logged in, might be something you want to check with them.

Comment: I have no answers for you, as I'm facing a similar problem (though it's for personal study); I can tell you one thing that I recently learned: servlets are stateless (so if you're going to check those _appID_ and _appPwd_ there you won't be able to distinguish from two different application users). I guess you'll better hand off the check and json generation to another bean.

Comment: Do they really only need a sample, or are they needing a simple but live application? If all they need is sample data for a handful of cases, just write text files and serve them up statically. If you do need to write a full app, don't touch Servlets directly; they're a very low-level tool. Instead, use something like Spring MVC; with Spring Boot, you can write an entire trivial application like this in about 25 lines.

Comment: @Anthony - This is a iPhone client, and they won't be using Ajax. All they need me to do is give them a request body, and a sample test page on a server they can hit, and would return 200.

Comment: @watery yes, servlets are stateless, but web-containers aren't.  You can get to a `HttpSession` using `HttpServletRequest.getSession()` into which you can store state.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Java Object that is formatted in the same format and then just use the built in methods

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/BasicWebServices"})
public class BasicWebServices extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static GsonBuilder gson_builder = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    public BasicWebServices(){
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy(){
          super.destroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        doPost(request, response);
    }
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        try{
            Gson gson = BasicWebServices.gson_builder.create();
            MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
            response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(myObject));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            response.getWriter().write("ERROR");
        }
    }
 }
```

Then you just have to make your MyObject the same setup as your retrieved values.
Either make an object that is setup the same, or if you can use the same java class as the one sending it if possible.

For your's you would have to have a class MyApp and then have the objects mAppHeader and requestPayload

```
public class mAppHeader(){
    String appId = "";
    String personId = "";
    String serviceName = "";
    String clientIP = "";
    String requestTimeStamp = "";     
    String encoding = "";
    String inputDataFormat = "";
    String outputDataFormat = "";
    String environment = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In doGet Method use Gson jarLibrary to generate JSON response

like below

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
HashMap map = new HashMap();

map.put("MyApp",object);

String jsonString = gson.toJson(map);
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.print(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Google's JSON library GSON, for parsing and forming of the JSON string.It eases your life. Look at the following link for reference.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/creating-parsing-json-data-with-java-servlet-struts-jsp-json/

You can also refer to the following link http://nareshkumarh.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/jquery-ajax-json-servlet-example/

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to pass some parameters from the client to the server, but show both a JSON message and then your servlet code looks as though the parameters are passed with request.

If you intend to pass JSON in the request body, the server will not automatically parse this for you, so your calls `request.getParameter("appID")` and `request.getParameter("appPwd")` won't work.

Instead you'll need to parse the body like this (based on the example message above):

```
JsonObject jsonRequest = Json.createReader(request.getInputStream()).readObject();

JsonObject authenticationRequestData = jsonRequest
  .getJsonObject("MyApp")
  .getJsonObject("requestPayload")
  .getJsonObject("body")
  .getJsonObject("request")
  .getJsonObject("MyTestApp")
  .getJsonObject("data")
  .getJsonObject("AuthenticationRequestData");

App app = new App();
app.setAppID(authenticationRequestData.getJsonString("appID"));
app.setAppPassword(authenticationRequestData.getJsonString("appPwd"));
```

Once your servlet has the object you want to use to create a response, you can simply generate the JSON and write it using `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()` like this:

```
SomeObject someObject = app.doSomething();

JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
 .add("someValue", someObject.getSomeValue())
 .add("someOtherValue", someObject.getSomeOtherValue())
 .build();

response.setContentType("application/json");
Json.createJsonWriter(response.getWriter()).writeObject(jsonObject);
```